# Find the general solution to the exact equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution to the exact equation: 
$$(1+x^2)y''+4xy'+2y = \sin (x) .$$

I understand how to do general solution for first order exact equation, how do we come about to solve second order.

Comment: See [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveExactLinearSecondOrderODEs.html).

Answer (score 0):

$u = (1+x^2) y\\
u' = 2x y + (1+x^2)y'\\
u'' = 2y + 4x y' + (1+x^2)y''$

$u'' = \sin x\\
u = -\sin x + Ax + B\\
y = \frac {-\sin x + Ax + B}{1+x^2}$

Comment: what sort of method is this called

Comment: Haven't a clue what you would call this method.  As it happened, the coefficients of $y$ were nicely behaved.  If not, it gets a little messier.  Nonetheless, you should look for a substitution that alows you to turn a  2nd order diff eq  to a first order equation.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. In simple cases like this (so this is not a general approach), try to see if there is a function $f(x)$ such that
$$(f(x)y(x))''=f(x)y''(x)+2f'(x)y'(x)+f''(x)y(x)$$
is equal to the left-hand side of your equation.